# how to simplify this expression in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have the following expression and was hoping to learn Scala more by knowing how to simplify it.

```
val r : Either[Exception, Long] = Right(100)
r fold (_ => (), uuid => account.setAccountUuid(uuid.toString))
```

Is it possible to make it even less verbose than this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive my troglodytism:

```
if ( r.isRight ) account.setAccountUuid(r.right.get.toString)
```

Doesn't readability count for *anything*??? Sometimes the Scala community seems to be all zealous [hammer-holders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) -- sorry, I meant monad-holders.

**Updated** to correct TravisBrown's catch (missing "get").

Comment: The irony is that `r.right.toString` will give you a string representation of the right projection (i.e. `"RightProjection(Right(foo))"`), which is a bug that you almost certainly wouldn't have run into if you'd been using that hammer.

Comment: @TravisBrown ouch!  It reinforces my underlying concern about readability, though.

Answer (score 6):

My initial answer was `r.right foreach (account.setAccountUuid(_.toString))` but it turns out that it triggers the dreade "missing parameter type for expanded function" error. I should have ssen this one coming.
How about:

```
for (i <- r.right) account.setAccountUuid(i.toString)
```

Comment: You should be able to use `foreach` by specifying an argument like this: `r.right.foreach(i => account.setAccountUuid(i.toString)`. Alternatively, `r.right.map(_.toString).foreach(account.setAccountUuid)`.

Comment: Agreed, your first alternative is IMHO equivalent in terms of readability (though marginally longer). However your second alternative does not look like an imporvment, and actually does not compile because `RightProjection.map` returns an `Either` and not another `RightProjection`. 
So you'd need to slap another call to `right` before `foreach` (making it even more verbose).

Comment: Good catch, and serves me right for not putting it through the compiler first!

Answer (score 0):

```
r fold (_ => (), account.setAccountUuid(_.toString))
```